# Marklogic faceted search and collations

Tags: search, marklogic, collation

I'm setting up a faceted search in MarkLogic. I have the following range indexes configured:

[image]

That is, I have two indexes. The first is on namespace `http://www.corbas.co.uk/ns/presentations` and local name `keyword`. The second has the local name `level`. The collation URI for both is `http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1`.

When I try to search using the following I see errors related to collations:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";


import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search("levels:Intermediate",
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <return-results>true</return-results>
  <return-facets>true</return-facets>

  <constraint name="keywords"  facet="true">
    <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1">
        <element ns="http://www.corbas.co.uk/ns/presentations" name="keyword"/>
    </range>
  </constraint>
  <constraint name="levels"  facet="true">
    <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1">
        <element ns="http://www.corbas.co.uk/ns/presentations" name="level"/>
    </range>
  </constraint>

</options>)
```

I get the following error:

```
XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:search(fn:collection(), 
cts:element-range query(fn:QName("http://www.corbas.co.uk/ns/presentations","level"), 
"=", "Intermediate", ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1"), 1), 
("score-logtfidf", "faceted", cts:score-order("descending")),
 xs:double("1"), ()) -- No string element range index for 
{http://www.corbas.co.uk/ns/presentations}level 
collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Strange Message. If it even got that far, then it looks like your database default collation is changed. Does not answer the question. just strange.

Forst off, I would always add the collation to the constraint:

```
<search:range type="xs:string" facet="true" 
       collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1">
```

Second, I always troubleshoot range index issue from the query console:
use `cts:values()` to verify that your indexes are in place and in the namespace and collation you expect. This removes other layers and verifies that the index is as you expect.

And another item: MarkLogic range indexes do not exist until content is indexed. Are you sure you have not turned off auto-index on the database and perhaps content is not indexed? That would give you an error.

Comment: I rebuilt the database (easy with Roxy) and recreated the index using the root collation. It all seems to work now but I'm now sure I can see *why*. Auto-index was on but I suspect I might have put the database into some sort of unusual state by constantly reloading the content as I try to understand this issue!

Comment: **NOT** sure, that is

Comment: I would have troubleshooted in queryConsole to understand the issue before having reloaded the database. While learning some of this, I would suggest a small sample set of data that will re-index almost instantly. I also turn off auto-indexing and do it under my control and refresh the database status page to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: I rebuilt into a new database - I still have the old. I was just checking to see that made a difference. Now that I have two databases with the same content where one works and one doesn't I can investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would have expected a different error message. I would have expected MarkLogic to complain it couldn't find an index for root collation, because you have not added `collation` attributes on the `range` elements in the search options.

Maybe adding those will help.

HTH!

Comment: Hmmm. I seem to have mispasted. Not sure where the collation attributes on the search went - have fixed the source code - same error applies.

Comment: What would the implication of the app server's default collation, the one specified on the index and the one queried not matching? Anything like this symptom?

Comment: The default collation on app-server (or in the prolog of your code) provides a default collation for cts functions, and string comparison. It only has affect if you don't explicitly specify collation. Always specifying it gives less surprises..

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your configuration is correct, which suggests to me that the problem is timing. Once you specify what indexes you want, MarkLogic gets to work creating them. If you run a query that requires those indexes before MarkLogic finishes creating them, you get this error. Depending on the amount of content you have, the creation process can be very quick or take hours.

To check the status, point your browser to the Admin UI (http://localhost:8001) and navigate to the configuration page for your database. Click on the Status tab and look for "Reindexing/Refragmenting State"—if MarkLogic is still reindexing, it will tell you so here and you'll get updates on its progress. (You can also get this information through [the Management API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]@view=status).)

Comment: The database is very very small for testing the ideas so the reindex is taking effectively no time. I'm pretty certain it's some sort of problem with the collations I'm using - as in I'm not using them correctly.